# Range query is not using indexes in mysql

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am trying to optimize the query which we are using to generate reports.
I think I did quite good to optimize to some extends.
Below was the original query:

```
select trat.asset_name as group_name,trat.name as sub_group_name,
       trat.asset_id as group_id,
       if(trat.cause_task_type='AccessRequest',true,false) as is_request_task,
       '' as grouped_on,
       concat(trat.asset_name,' - {0} (',count(*),')') as table_heading
    from t_remote_agent_tasks trat
    where trat.status in ('completed','failedredundant')
      and trat.name not in ('collect-data','update-conn-params')
    group by trat.asset_name, trat.name
    order by field(trat.name,'create-account','change-attr',
                             'add-member-to-group',
                             'grant-access','disable-account','revoke-access',
                             'remove-member-from-group','update-license')
```

When I see the execution plain in Extra column it says using where,Using Temporary,filesort.

So I optimize the query like this

```
select  trat.asset_name as group_name,trat.name as sub_group_name,
        trat.asset_id as group_id,
        if(trat.cause_task_type='AccessRequest',true,false) as is_request_task,
        '' as grouped_on,
        concat(trat.asset_name,' - {0} (',count(*),')') as table_heading
    from t_remote_agent_tasks trat
    where trat.status in ('completed','failedredundant')
      and trat.name not in ('collect-data','update-conn-params')
    group by trat.asset_name,trat.name
    order by null
```

Which gives me the execution plan as using where,using temporary. So filesort is no more use and there is no extra overhead as optimizer doesn't have to sort,which will be taken care during group by.

I again went forward and created indexes on group by columns in same order as they mentioned in group by(this is important or optimization won't happen) i.e create index on (trat.asset_name,trat.name).
Now this optimization gives me Using where only in extra column. Also the query execution time got deduced by almost half(earlier it was 0.568 sec. and now 0.345sec ,not exact though it vary every time but more or less in this range).

Now I want to optimize the range query ,below part of query

```
    trat.status in ('completed','failedredundant')
and trat.name not in ('collect-data','update-conn-params')
```

I am reading on [mysl reference guide to optimize range query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/range-optimization.html),Which says not in is not in range query ,So I did the modification in query like this

```
    trat.status in ('completed','failedredundant')
and trat.name in ('add-member-to-group','change-attr','create-account',
                  'disable-account','grant-access', 'remove-member-from-group',
                  'update-license')
```

But it doesn't show any improvement in Extra(I mean using index should be there,it is still showing using where).
I also tried by splitting both range part into unions(that will change the query result but still no improvement in execution plan)

I want some help on how to optimize this query more,mostly the range part(in part).
Any other optimization if I need to make on this?

I appreciate your time,Thanks in advance

## EDIT 1 I forgot to mentioned that I have index on trat.status also,So Below are the indexes

1. (trat.asset_name,trat.name)
2. (trat.status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In virtually all cases, only one index is used in a `SELECT`.  So, one must have available the best.

Both of the first two queries will *probably* benefit most from the same 'composite' index:

```
INDEX(asset_name, name)
```

Normally, one would try to handle the `WHERE` conditions in the index, but they do not look amenable to an index.  (More discussion below.)  Second choice is the `GROUP BY`, which I am recommending.  But, since (in the first case) the `ORDER BY` and the `GROUP BY` are different, there will necessarily be a tmp table created for the output of the `GROUP BY` so that it can be sorted according to the `ORDER BY`.  (There may also be a tmp and sort for the `GROUP BY`; I cannot tell.)

"Using index" means that a "covering" index was used.  A "covering" index is a composite index that includes *all* of the columns used *anywhere* in the `SELECT`.  That would be about 5 columns, and probably not wise to attempt.  (More below.)

Another thing to note that even something this simple:

```
WHERE x IN (11,22)
GROUP BY y
```

cannot use any index to handle both the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY`.  So, there is no way for your query to consume both (except by 'covering').

A covering index, when used, is only partially useful.  It says that all the work is done just in the BTree of the index.  But that could include a full index scan -- which is not that much faster than a full table scan.  This is another argument against recommending 'covering'.

In some situations, `IN` or `OR` can be sped up by turning it into `UNION`:

```
( SELECT ... WHERE status in ('completed') )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE status in ('failedredundant') )
```

but this will only cause you to stumble into the `NOT IN(...)` clause, which is worse than an `IN`.

The goal of finding the best index is to find one that has the rows (in the index and/or in the table) consecutively sitting in the BTree.

To make any further improvements on this query will probably require re-thinking the schema -- it seems to be forcing you to have `IN`, `NOT IN`, `FIELD` and other hard-to-optimize constructs.